# Google Oauth refresh_token has expiration time in Google Workspace with Internal User Type?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I developing an app for internal propose. Currently works OK, but I'm curious about if exists any expiration time since I create the initial **credentials.json** file. This is because previously in my Personal Google Account I saw a restriction over Testing Apps where the refresh_token only works for 7 days.

Currently, I using this code to generate the first time refresh_token and after that use client_id, client_secret, and refresh_token to regenerate every 2 minutes a new access_token

```
import os
from oauth2client import client, tools, file

SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'

def generate_inicital_credentials():
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
    
    # creates credentials with a refresh token
    credential_path = os.path.join('credentials.json')
    store = file.Storage(credential_path)
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    return creds
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has an expiration, Google listed the reasons for why your refresh token might stop working:

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh - tokens.
- The user belongs to a Google Cloud Platform organization that has session control policies in effect.`

Here is some note from GCP for refresh tokens.

> Per OAuth 2.0 client ID, there is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per Google Account. When the limit is reached, establishing a new refresh token invalidates the previous refresh token without warning. Service accounts are exempt from this restriction.

> The overall number of refresh tokens a user account or service account can have across all clients is similarly limited. The majority of normal users will not go above this limit, however a developer's account used to test an implementation may.